# Subir archivos utilizando VueJS, Axios y .NET CORE

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, axios

Estoy teniendo problemas con la subida de archivos utilizando axios y ASP.Net Core. No se si el problema esté en mi funcion SubirArchivos del frontend o el problema sea en el controller. Les muestro como esta mi codigo:

**Axios**

Funcion para realizar la peticion al backend:

```
SubirArchivos(){              

            let formData = new FormData();

            for( var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ){
            let file = this.files[i];

            formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
            }

            axios.post( 'api/Documentos/UploadFiles',
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }
            ).then(function(){
            console.log('Correcto!');
            })
            .catch(function(){
            console.log('Error!');
            });
        }
```

**c#**

Esto es en mi controller:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
    }
```

El problema que tengo pienso yo que es en el backend, pues a la hora de recorrer la lista "files" no contiene ningún archivo.

Estoy haciendo referencia a estos dos links

- https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Tu pregunta esta muy bien formulada. Podrias leer el [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos?

Answer (score 1):

Después de estar buscando, encontré esto y me funcionó.

Utilizar en el controller `IFormCollection` en lugar de `List<IFormFile>`, les dejo el bloque de código:

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]        
    public async Task<IActionResult> SubirArchivos(IFormCollection UploadedFiles)
    {
        long size = UploadedFiles.Files.Sum(f => f.Length);
        string ruta = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Uploads\\XML");           

        foreach (var formFile in UploadedFiles.Files)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = formFile.FileName;
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(ruta, fileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok(new { archivos = UploadedFiles.Files.Count, size, ruta });
    }
```

Cambie un poco mi función para poder subir los archivos a una carpeta en mi servidor.

Comment: Antes de guardar, verifica que el archivo sea inexistente para guardarlo, porque si tuvieras el mismo nombre de archivo, se va a sobre escribir...